# NSMatrix drawing outside bounds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a fairly simple custom view class, that is contained inside an NSSplitView. That view class inits itself by adding an NSMatrix and a couple dummy cells. The really weird thing is that despite being sized to fill it's superview, it's actually significantly taller and wider than the superview. I tried to log the frame and bounds, the results are below as well, but I'm stumped. Why isn't this sizing to it's superview as I'd expect?

[image: Launches like this]
[image: Looks like this when I resize]

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSImageCell *prototypeCell = [[NSImageCell alloc] init];
        [prototypeCell setBordered:YES];

        _matrix = [[NSMatrix alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds
                                             mode:NSHighlightModeMatrix
                                        prototype:prototypeCell
                                     numberOfRows:1
                                  numberOfColumns:1];

        [_matrix setCellSize:NSMakeSize(50, 50)];

        [_matrix setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
        _matrix.drawsBackground = YES;

        [_matrix addRow];

        NSCell *cell = [_matrix cellAtRow:0 column:0];
        [cell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"block.png"]];

        cell = [_matrix cellAtRow:1 column:0];
        [cell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"block.png"]];

        [self addSubview:_matrix];

        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(self.bounds));
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(self.frame));
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(_matrix.bounds));
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(_matrix.frame));
    }
    return self;
}
```

---

```
Output:
2014-02-15 15:16:23.458 Temp[5970:303] {{0, 0}, {45, 331}}
2014-02-15 15:16:23.459 Temp[5970:303] {{500, 0}, {45, 331}}
2014-02-15 15:16:23.459 Temp[5970:303] {{0, 0}, {45, 331}}
2014-02-15 15:16:23.459 Temp[5970:303] {{0, 0}, {45, 331}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven’t set up either autolayout constraints or old-fashioned springs-n-struts to keep your matrix sticking to the edges of its parent view.

My suspicion is you’re running with state restoration on, so on launch the parent view is being created at one size, then the state restores and the window / splitView resize and the subview no longer matches its parent.

In general, if you create a view yourself, immediately add constraints (or call `-setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable` [in this case] if you’re not using autolayout).

Comment: You are absolutely right.. I had pulled that out trying to chase other issues, and forgot to re-insert.. Thank you!